Confusion about how this part of inequality is true.
I was reading this solution off from a book that provided a solution to the question:
Suppose that $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n,\cdots$ are all real numbers such that $0\le a_{i} \le 1$ for $i=1,2,3,\cdots$ . Prove that for every $n \ge 2$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+a_{i}}\le \frac{n}{1+\sqrt[n]{a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n}}}$$
The solution the book offered first proves the inequality by taking the form of $n=2^{m}$, the base case $m=1$ is simple but the part that I'm confused is the following:
Assume $m=k$, then below is true up to $k$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2^k}\frac{1}{1+a_{i}}\le\frac{2^k}{1+\sqrt[2^k]{a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{2^k}}}$$
Then for $m=k+1$,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2^{k+1}}\frac{1}{1+a_i}\le \sum_{i=1}^{2^k}\left(\frac{1}{1+a_{2i-1}} + \frac{1}{1+a_{2i}} \right) \le 2\sum_{i=1}^{2^k}\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{a_{2i-1}a_{2i}}}$$
And then,
$$2\sum_{i=1}^{2^k}\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{a_{2i-1}a_{2i}}} \le 2 \ \cdot \frac{2^k}{1+\sqrt[2^k]{\sqrt{a_{1}a_{2}}\sqrt{a_{3}a_{4}}\cdots \sqrt{a_{2^{k+1}-1}a_{2^{k+1}}}}}=\frac{2^{k+1}}{1+\sqrt[k-1]{a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{2^{k+1}}}}$$
Which proves the inequality (for $n=2^m$ where $m \in \mathbb{N}$).

The part that I'm confused is why
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2^k}\left(\frac{1}{1+a_{2i-1}} + \frac{1}{1+a_{2i}} \right) \le 2\sum_{i=1}^{2^k}\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{a_{2i-1}a_{2i}}}$$
is this true? Is there some sort of application of HM-GM inequality that I'm apparently missing?

That's just applying the base case, which you already said is simple. Namely, when $m = 1, n = 2$
$$ \frac{1}{1 + a }  + \frac{1}{1+b} \leq \frac{ 2}{ 1 + \sqrt{ab} }. $$
Then you sum it up over the $2^k$-many indices.
This is quite standard for such forward-backwards induction proof for inequalities, so I'd recommend you to look through more of those. The power of it is that you just need to solve the two-variable case, which often can be brute forced.
